# Unable to change screen resolution in 22.04.2

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics, display-resolution

Hopefully someone can help me I've been searching and trying various things for days.
It seems to have only one resolution available which is 1024x768 yet when I boot into other O/S I have different options to choose from. The GPU is integrated on the MB as shows up as a generic Microsoft driver.
[screen clip of machine details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc0OQ.png)

When I check the details in terminal this is what I get:

phil@phil-X455LAB:~$ sudo lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)

I also have to boot into recovery mode and edit the bootloader to use nomodeset otherwise I just have a black screen with a flashing cursor.
TIA
Phil